# Empty comments in Angular application

Tags: angular, angular-cli, tsconfig

Is there any configuration setting which would remove these empty comments and whitespace?

[image]

My build command is `ng build --environment prod --progress false --target production` and tsconfig is:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "baseUrl": "/",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "newLine": "CRLF",
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "removeComments": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types" ]
    }
}
```

@angular/cli: 1.0.4
node: 7.2.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.1.3

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is generated based on your Angular directive, tag, conditions(if,for...), so this **blank space is required**. If you remove that then it will not behave well all two way bindings will gone away. Those space **determine** how your **angular DOM** will render and bind to Model and variables. Also the comment **keep track where new DOM element will render**(if conditions and other).

Refer this link for more information: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8722

Answer (score 5):

Every one of those comments is a `ViewContainerRef` that Angular uses to keep the spot for an expression that could render a view.

when you have an `ngIf`, if the expression is evaluated as false, obviously Angular wont render the element, but as soon as it becomes true, it will render the element, so how does it know where to put it ?

```
   <div *ngIf="expression"></div>
```

Of course other expression evaluation and view template bindings are there, but `ngIf` is the easiest one to understand

That's where those comments come from.

Answer (score 2):

you simply can't!

Angular needs these comments to keep track of many things like where to render the `*ngIf` content
so long story short comments need to be in your HTML or Angular simply will not work.

Comment: Are these comments displayed as empty only in Chrome developer tools? Otherwise, I don't see how <!----> can help angular. I had an idea, that tsconfig option "removeComments" should not be used with an angular app, but the app strangely works as expected.